# How "...android.googlesource.../external/icu/" used by android studio & ndk?

Tags: android

as the title, i try all my efforts to find out how to use it, but failed. there isn't any manual/readme to guide.
obsolutely, I'm a rookie.
can any one give some advices?
[android.googlesource.../external/icu/ address](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/icu/+/refs/heads/master)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not expected to use the Git repository alone.

See https://source.android.com/setup/develop - there is a tool called `repo` which stitches together a collection of Git repositories, controlled by a manifest (itself versioned in Git). If you follow the directions for checking out AOSP, you will find that repository at `platform/external/icu`, where it can get built by the top-level build system.

It's not really feasible to use Android Studio on the whole AOSP project. If you're looking to make use of ICU within your own NDK project, you should bundle your own; the platform's ICU is not made available to non-platform native code.